# How to sign rpm packages using digital signatures?

Tags: rpm, sign

I know there is a way to sign using keys but my requirement is to sign using digital certificates.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
# rpm -ba --sign blather-7.9.spec
            Enter pass phrase: <passphrase> (Not echoed)

Pass phrase is good.
* Package: blather
…
Binary Packaging: blather-7.9-1
Finding dependencies...
…
Generating signature: 1002
Wrote: /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/i386/blather-7.9-1.i386.rpm
…
Source Packaging: blather-7.9-1
…
Generating signature: 1002
Wrote: /usr/src/redhat/SRPMS/blather-7.9-1.src.rpm
#
```